# how to send a multipart post (to send images) as a soap packet?

Tags: php, soap, curl

I want to upload images to some server using multipart post request.
I am using PHP/cURL to send soap request envelopes

Any help would be very appreciated.

Amjad

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit unsure what excatly you are trying to do. If you want to include images in a SOAP request, you should send the binary content of that image as base64 encoded string (using PHPs [`base64_encode`](http://www.php.net/base64_encode) function).

If you could update your answer with more details what you are trying to achieve and maybe post some code, we could provide you with better answers.

Comment: Yes, I want to send an image with SOAP Request but target server is not supporting base64 method. Instead, I have to use a multi part post request just as we send through a simple html form with some target URL. Or may be I need some more better way but not finding one yet.

Comment: @Amjad Shaick - hm, but attachments in multipart messages are normally base64 encoded, too. What do you mean that the target server does not support base64 encoding?

Comment: I got this instruction from service provider: NOTE: images are specified in binary (not Base64) format.  Also, the Content-Disposition header uses “form-data; name="filename"; filename="format (not “attachment; filename =’’ format).

Comment: @Amjad Shaick Hm, did you try to send the raw binary content of an image along? So, just the content you get when using file_get_contents('your_img.png'); ?

Comment: Can we achieve this through PHP/cURL ?